# Как сделать так, чтобы при передаче аргументов классу не учитывался аргумент self?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Я только начал изучать ООП и мне показалось интересным сделать проверку класса на ошибки,
но при запуске моего кода у меня выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Я\Python\proects\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    Class.StartTest()
  File "C:\Users\Я\Python\proects\test.py", line 17, in StartTest
    test_unit.self.name_function()
AttributeError: 'main' object has no attribute 'self'
```

Вот мой код ---

```py
class main():
    def __init__(self, name, addr):
        self.name=name
        self.addr=addr
    def Fun(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name.title(),self.addr.lower())


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name_class, args, name_function):
        self.name_class=name_class
        self.args=args
        self.name_function=name_function
    def StartTest(self):
        test_unit=self.name_class(*self.args)
        test_unit.self.name_function()


Class=TestClass(main, ['adA', 'LoVeLacE'], main.Fun)
Class.StartTest()
```

Скажите, как избавиться от этой ошибки, ведь при передаче аргументов напрямую все нормально, а при передаче аргументов классу через другой класс возникает данная ошибка

Answer (score 1):

В функции `StartTest` последняя строчка должна быть `print(self.name_function(test_unit))`, ну или `return ...`, смотря чего Вы хотите...

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в ошибке все написано. У объекта `test_unit` у Вас нет атрибута `self`. Вы в класс закидываете класс, список с параметрами и метод класса. Вам в итоге надо работать с объектом класса при тестировании, а Вы пытаетесь из `test_unit` вытащить его самого.

Мое мнение, что в Вашем случае, если вы хотите тестировать какой-то внутренний метод, то Вам нужно получать объект из тестируемого класса, а потом с ним работать. В Вашей постановке надо вытащить имя метода через магию `__name__` (см. пример ниже), а уже после через `getattr(object, name)` вытащить из объекта ссылку на метод и запустить его.

```
class ExampleClass():
    def __init__(self, name, addr):
        self.name = name
        self.addr = addr

    def fun(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name.title(), self.addr.lower())


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name_class, args, name_function):
        self.name_class = name_class
        self.args = args
        self.name_function = name_function.__name__

    def start_test(self):
        test_unit = getattr(self.name_class(*self.args), self.name_function)
        return test_unit()


case = TestClass(ExampleClass, ['adA', 'LoVeLacE'], ExampleClass.fun)
print(case.start_test())
```

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось

Answer (score 0):

Метод класса и метод экземпляра это разные вещи. Если метод вызывать от класса, то в self передается тип, а не экземпляр. Когда вы сделали инициализацию строкой выше, то экземпляр вернулся, но связь с методом, который получили ранее у него не возникла.